# Mendeley Citation Key for Citation Style

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am using Mendeley to manage all my references and also used it to cite in Word. Now I am trying to convert the Word document to LaTeX, but it seems that I have to manually convert all my citations to match `\cite{CITATION_KEY}`. I thought that I could maybe create my own citation style that uses exactly this format but it seems that I cannot access the citation key in the Visual CSL Editor. Is that somehow possible? Converting all the citations myself it a lot of work. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: You could try writing a macro in a text editor that simply copies the citation key to an unused field like `keyword` for example. Then create a citation style with the CLS editor that quotes like `\cite{keyword}`

Comment: Yea, I have written a node.js script that I run to replace all inline citations with LaTeX citations. First, I had to create a dictionary that I used as a lookup table. A key is the number used in the Word document, and the value is the citation key from the `.bib` file. Works fine. Still, it required some manual work. Would be awesome if Mendeley would support such thing.

Comment: Just figured - one could've also copied the citation keys into a keyword via a SQLite script on the database.

Comment: @Mace considered to write an answer?

Comment: I'm looking to do exactly the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Using an SQLite editor you can edit the Mendeley database directly and run a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837070/in-sqlite-how-do-i-copy-data-from-one-column-to-another-column-in-the-same-table#4837085) which copies the `citation key` of all entries into an unused field, for example `keyword`. 
Now create a citation style using the Visual CSL editor, that states inline citations like `\cite{keyword}`

*Note:* I did not check if `keyword` is a field which is addressable by the Word citation plugin or the CSL editor. Obviously, the field you choose has to be.