# Using Google Docs and Papertile references in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Warning: Completely new to this

I have written my whole document in Google docs and referenced using Papertile.

I got the `.bib` file by going to `Papertile->reference->references as bibtex` and uploaded the *ref.bib* to the overleaf project I am working on.

I have added the following and can confirm that referencing works when I use \cite and include the article name

```
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\cite{greenwade93}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

I have some 300+ references in my google doc, which citation style should I use on my google doc text to ensure that the references appear in the overleaf automatically without individually replacing all 300+ with \cite ?

[image]

Here is a sample text from my google docs with IEEE styling using papertile

A network of .....[2]. LAN circuits are ...... [3]. The exchange ....[3-5], [9].

Comment: It looks like papertile uses CSL, so one way to go would be using a citation style, that prints the bibtex key, like in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386401/29873

Comment: @DG' I am very confused with that answer...Which citation style should I select in google docs?

Comment: @DG' I can replace all numbers [1] with \cite, that is fine. What is the common citation style between overleaf and paperleaf?